# jquery sidebar is not working

Tags: jquery, sidebar, margin-left

I have two sidebars and left and right and centre box.
if both sidebar is slide out using margin-left:"0" and margin-right: "0" then center box become full width.

I wrote jquery if statements and is not working what I"m missing.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        if ($(".sidebar-nav").css("marginLeft")=='0px' && (".sidebar-nav-right").css("marginRightt")=='0px') {
        $(".center-box").css("margin-right", "0"); 
        $(".center-box").css("margin-left", "0"); 
    } else {
        $(".center-box").css("background" , "red"); 
    }
});
```

Comment: Please post the complete html and css so that we can see what the issue might be. If possible, please post a fiddle.

Comment: inconsistent... `("marginRightt") ("margin-Right") ("margin-right")`

Comment: try using  $(".center-box").css({backgroundColor: "red"}); and $(".center-box").css({margin-right: "0px"});